# How do I work with onItemSelected method?

Tags: android, spinner

```
    int I, E
    String[] type;
    Spinner firstSpinner ;
    Spinner secondSpinner ;
    Spinner thirdSpinner;
    Spinner fourthSpinner;    

public void addItemsOnSpinner4(){   
            Spinner firstSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.spinnerarraybool, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            firstSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        }       
        //ACTIONS THAT TAKE PLACE WHEN SPINNER OPTION IS CHOSEN
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            switch (parent.getId()){
            case R.id.spinner4:
                String firstAnswer = firstSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if (firstAnswer.equals("True")){
                    E += 1;
                }
                if (firstAnswer.equals("In the Middle")){
                    E += 1;
                    I += 1;
                }
                if (firstAnswer.equals("False")){
                    I += 1;
                }
                break;


<STRINGSXMLstring-array name="spinnerarraybool">
    <item>True</item>
    <item>In the Middle</item>
    <item>False</item>
</STRINGSXMLstring-array>
```

The values of E and I are not changing and staying at 0.  How do I fix my onItemSelected method to make them change.  I would like I and E to go up whenever I select an option in my spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to call `firstSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);` after setting the adapter

Answer (score 0):

```
firstSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) 
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) 
            {

            }
        });
```